# Remove Elements from a Nested arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
{"data":[{"hotelfloorsid":"1","floorname":"Ground Floor"},{"hotelfloorsid":"2","floorname":"1st Floor"},{"hotelfloorsid":"9","floorname":"3rd Floor"}]}
```

I want to remove element from this array based on hotelfloorsid.

Comment: Use Array.filter or the equivalent of it from a library like lodash, ie.: _.filter

Comment: `obj.data.filter(function(item) { return item.hotelfloorsid > 1 });`

Answer (score 1):

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove items from an array.

```
var data = //your object - e.g. {data:[array of data]};
var newData = data.data.filter(function(object) {
   return object.hotelfloorsid == 1; //only include rooms where hotelfloorsid is 1
});
```

Comment: data.filter(function(object) right?